# How do I set the login manager to enable `change languages` at login?

Tags: keyboard-layout, login-screen, lightdm, input-language, language-support

How can I recompile the source to force the option to allow changing languages and keyboard layouts at login?

Comment: Why don't use `gdm` instead of `lightdm`?

Answer (score 3):

Did you install the language packs from **Language support** ?

### Update

I seem to have mixed the keyboard layout with the language support!

There is a solution provided in a bug report:
[Comment #16](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/803858):

> There is now an optional language selector in the GTK greeter for
> desktops that require it. To enable it set show-language-selector=true
> in /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf. Fixed in 0.9.8.

### Solution

Execute this command:

> gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf

Find the line:

```
#show-language-selector=false
```

Change it to:

```
show-language-selector=true
```

Save and exit. Logout / Login or reboot the machine to apply the effect.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer.

If I got it right, that icon will only change the keyboard layout while I’m log in?

I need the possibility to alter the system language after login.
Using the old login screen, I just selected the user.
After that, there was different options in the bottom of the screen.
The leftmost icon was a globe followed by option to set the system language after login.

If there is no equal option in the new login screen- how can I return to the old one?

Best regards
Bosch

Comment: Could you test this solution please? [Quoting comment #16](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/803858): *There is now an optional language selector in the GTK greeter for desktops that require it. To enable it set show-language-selector=true in /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf. Fixed in 0.9.8.*

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly turn on the language selector in the login screen according to [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/803858):

> To enable it set `show-language-selector=true` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`.

Comment: I tried this on 12.04 and it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using 14.04 or greater
Find this

```
show-indicators=
```

in

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

and then add to end of line

```
~language;
```