# Select language From Login screen

Tags: login-screen, swap, language-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the login manager to enable `change languages` at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92297/how-do-i-set-the-login-manager-to-enable-change-languages-at-login)

I believe it was possible to select language before login in Ubuntu 10.04.
I can't find that feature in 11.10 - is there a way?
Do I have to switch to gnome to get this feature?

I want to setup a computer for a lobby, where people with different native languages and with limited computer skill can login.

Also would like to have an automatically solution when the question if the folder names will change name?

Answer (score 1):

You simple can use `gdm` instead of `lightdm`. The former was the default Ubuntu graphical login manager, before it was substituted by the latter.

`gdm` is not installed by default anymore, so you need to install it.