# How to swap the language before login as per the old GDM login screen?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, lightdm, login-screen, language-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the login manager to enable `change languages` at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92297/how-do-i-set-the-login-manager-to-enable-change-languages-at-login)

I used to run Ubuntu 10.04 on an computer.
When upgarde to 12.04 I have got a totally new login screen.
I'm lacking of the oppertumnity to easily swap the language before login I used to have in the old version.
Is there any possibility to get that login screen back?
An alternative is how to get the possibilty to easily swap langauge before login?
Note, the computer is located in a lobby where people with different native langauge will use it.

best regards
Bosch