# Make GDM3 in Ubuntu 12.10 show a list of available languages

Tags: gdm, language-support, locale

The local computer pool is used by a large number of students that prefer to choose the language of the Ubuntu desktop. Not all want English. Unfortunately, the GDM login manager does not present a list of available languages installed on the System.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently and upstream decision (Gnome's):

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671528

Also reported in RedHat and Debian's bug trackers:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=681750
- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=638353

In short, that functionality is gone.

As a workaround it seems LightDM provides this, check this question:
[How do I set the login manager to enable `change languages` at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92297/how-do-i-set-the-login-manager-to-enable-change-languages-at-login)